# How to clear Query Messages?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**How can I clear the Messages buffer in a query?**

actually I don't want to see any messages there after my query finishes. consider that, I'm using `PRINT` statement in my query! also my query may print some error messages with/without `RAISEERROR`.

Comment: Do you mean want to clear Messages Tab of Sql Server Managements?

Comment: #qotqn `SET NONCOUNT ON` just prevents to print affected rows count not clearing the tab! It must be called at the first of my query which i can't access there! and at last, it doesn't affect on `RAISEERROR` messages :)

Comment: I don't think that there's a way. SQL Server itself knows nothing of the messages tab, so it would have to be a command interpreted by SSMS. The only command I'm aware of that is interpreted by SSMS instead of SQL Server is `GO` for separating batches.

Comment: Why you want to do this

Comment: You do not want anything to be printed in the messages tab, even `PRINT` command output and error messages or you want them to be printed, but cleared upon completion of execution?

Comment: Why do you have print statements if you don't want any output?

Comment: @Raj the second one, I want to be printed, but cleared upon completion.

Comment: @Fireblade I am responsible to write an Stored Procedure which is called by an other Stored Procedure on another server which I can't access. The caller SP prints something in output including error messages, statistics, debug messages etc. Now, the remote SP is called which executes my SP. The problem is, I HAVE to Print some messages that Next developers in chain grab them in ADO.NET which is very important unfortunately!

Comment: very good Mr. Zakery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is actually no way to hide custom PRINT messages. You can only hide

- Number of rows effected ([SET NOCOUNT ON;](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx))
- SQL Warning ([SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx))

Consider below example

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

BEGIN TRY

SELECT 1
PRINT 'Some message'

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH

    RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'Some Error Message ');
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this Code in your Query Window:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Refer this link for more Detail

[SET NOCOUNT ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)