# delete part of print output (messages pane SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When running a cursor, I put some code to help me keep track of its progress. Here is a sample output of the print function:

> Progress: Iteration 1200 / 3644 (32.93 %)
>     Elapsed: 00:01:08:670
>   Estimated remaining: 00:02:19:857
>    Estimated total: 00:03:28:527

I am using SSMS, so this appears in the "Messages" pane. The next identical block will be printed underneath. This is not pleasing to the eye, as well as being uncomfortable since the messages pane does not autoscroll.

**Is there some way to clear a specific portion of the messages pane? Something like sending backspaces?**

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language, don't treat it like one. The messages pane is purely to display the output messages, such as `PRINT`. If you're worried about something that is graphically "unpleasing" create an application with a progress bar.

Comment: I feel like the real question here, however, is why are you using a `CURSOR`? They are so very rarely implemented when they are actually needed.

Comment: @Larnu I actually really, really try to avoid cursors. However, in case of error we want to work succesful rows and keep errors for problematic ones. Since errors are rare, i even try-catched a set operation before going in the cursor. I can still not avoid it, though. Also, this "cursor progress" is something i did only for me as a debug convenience, so it won't go as far as to be made as a new app.

Comment: Sounds like you should be validating the rows before inserting then, not doing them row by agonising row.

Comment: I do set validation preparation, but I cannot be prepared for any error out there. I hope the cursor actually never fires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Query Messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647921/how-to-clear-query-messages)

Comment: @3Ν19Μ4 No, that prevents (certain) output, it does not delete-overwrite it.