# How to clear Messages in SQL Server in runtime

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to clear the messages output whilst running a query in SSMS? I have a procedure that is using the `PRINT` instruction to inform me of how a looped query is progressing, but as there can be thousands of loops, I'd rather just have the latest loop number displayed, rather than it printing underneath each time.

So something like:

```
WHILE @batch < @totalBatches
BEGIN
    (TASK SQL HERE)

    Print 'Progress so far: batch ' + @batch + ' of ' + @totalbatches + ' batches'
    <Clear Messages Command?>

    set @batch +=1
END
```

Where (Task SQL Here) is my code doing the work, and <Clear Messages Command?> is the command I am unsure of, if it even exists.

I've been doing some searching on the internet, including SO, but can't find anything that seems to cover this, only using things like `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Query Messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647921/how-to-clear-query-messages) [SSMS clean output window with sql instruction](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144711/ssms-clean-output-window-with-sql-instruction) also says "no".

Comment: Have you considered insert a new record to a log table, or updating a log table with the newest record. I'm pretty sure print just echo's what it's told and it's the client which is actually holding on to the information... so it really comes down to the options of the client your connecting to the database

Comment: @AndrewMorton, that link does go some way to answering, but the answer seemed to be more about hiding messages than clearing existing messages. I wonder whether the newer versions of SQL Server has some added functionality that addresses this now?

Comment: @Monofuse, that could be an idea. Perhaps that might be the way round the limitations

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the second link you provided does seem to be quite conclusive that it's not possible. It's a bit frustrating, but I suppose it's not what the messages window is for. It would have been nice though! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the progress after a certain % has been completed.

e.g. every 5% :

```
DECLARE @batch int = 1;
DECLARE @totalBatches int = 100;
DECLARE @PtInterval int = 5;


WHILE @batch < @totalBatches
BEGIN
    --(TASK SQL HERE)

    set @batch +=1;

    IF (100 * @batch / @totalBatches / @PtInterval) <> 100 * (@batch-1) / @totalBatches / @PtInterval
        PRINT CONCAT( 100 * @batch / @totalBatches, '% completed');

END;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good take on it to reduce the total returned lines. I've +1 for your answer as it doesn't directly answer the problem, but it a good alternative.